# How do I remove "Circle Scaling"?

Tags: selection-tools, scale

i don't even know how I activated this. It's not the circle selection tool "C". It's a circle that appears when im trying to scale de UV Maps.
[image: Circle appears only pressing the scale tool]

[image: Once I begin to scale it gets like this]

Comment: [Press O](http://builder.openhmd.net/blender-hmd-viewport-temp/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html).

Comment: I guess the Proportional Editing option is activated (blue sphere icon on the horizontal menu bar)